# Rules - How can I put a link into an email sent by a rule

Tags: rules, emails

I would like to use rules to send an email to my admin staff when a new piece of content is created.  It would be great if the email contained a link to the content to make it easier to find.  Is there a way to insert the link?  Perhaps there is a token that I could use.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following: `[site:url]user/login?destination=node/[node:nid]/edit`.

This will show login form to the users who are not authenticated and then redirect them to the node edit page.

If the user is already logged in, he/she will be immediately taken to the node edit page.

Comment: That looks great!  Could I also use: [site:login-url]?destination=node/[node:nid]/edit

Comment: Also, do I need to wrap the link in an anchor tag?

Comment: Yes and yes. The token will just return the URL, so you need to put it in the anchor tag.

Comment: can I write  the anchor tag directly into the rules field or will it get filtered (if filtered, can I prevent this?)

Comment: You can write it there directly. Just now realized one thing: if you aren't already sending HTML email, just leave the URL as is, without an anchor tag. If the email is sent as plain text, most of the email clients/apps will render the URL as a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: [node:edit-url]